# Set BackColor for RadDock in Telerik Rad Controls Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have used RadDock in my windows application and it loads the tool window inside it. I am able to change the background color for tool window but not able to do for RadDock. Please suggest me a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```vb
Dim window As HostWindow
Dim uc As UserControl1 = New UserControl1()
Dim tw As ToolWindow = New ToolWindow()
tw.Controls.Add(Panel2)
Me.RadDock1.DockControl(tw, DockPosition.Right, DockType.ToolWindow)
window = DirectCast(RadDock1.ActiveWindow, HostWindow)
window.ToolCaptionButtons = ToolStripCaptionButtons.AutoHide
window.DockState = DockState.AutoHide
RadDock1.AutoHideWindows(New DockWindow() {tw}, AutoHidePosition.Right)
tw.BackColor = Color.Green
```

Comment: You want change color of raddock content?

Comment: @mww: I want to change the color of raddock control itself.  Defaultly it is in light blue color i want to change that

Comment: This blue color is from default theme. You have to set to all controls same theme or turn it off.(telerikControlName.EnableApplicationThemeName =false)